# FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger - как решить проблему android?

Tags: android, google-play-console

В Google Play Console после очередного тестирования прилетели ошибки такого типа:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet, PID: 14483
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData.clearAdapter(NoteData.kt:274)
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData.access$clearAdapter(NoteData.kt:26)
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData$getRemarksList$1.onResponse(NoteData.kt:284)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:141)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:97)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

и таких ошибок нашлось в 6 устройствах из 12. Видел этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989287/playstore-android-pre-launch-test-fatal-exception-controllermessenger), там речь шла о каких-то ложных срабатываниях. Проблема в том что гугл находит ошибки в совершенно странных местах. Я не говорю что у меня приложение идеальное, просто они влезают в такие дебри и находят такие ошибки которые временами вообще никак не относятся к приложению. Как можно решить данную ошибку?

### UPDATE

строка ошибки:

```
at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData.clearAdapter(NoteData.kt:274)
```

фрагмент кода:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dialog!!.setOnKeyListener { _, code, event ->
        if (code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                webView.clearHistory()
                dialog!!.dismiss() // строка 274
                true
            } else {

                true
            }
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В данном случае у вас там `null` на определённой строке. Покажите код, на котором оно падает - может сможем предположить что могло пойти не так)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, обновил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну, собственно заменить все `dialog!!` на `dialog?` и падать не будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, возможно глупая просьба, но тем не менее - оформите как ответ пожалуйста, или тут напишите, если не сложно в чем смысл !! и ?, я то знаю что это проверка на null но в чем именно их смысл не очень понимаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде в паре мест есть код вида `dialog!!.` что означает - выкини NPE если `dialog` `null`. Именно эту ошибку вы и получаете.

Чтобы ошибка не возникала, то вызывать методы на этой переменной надо только если она не `null`. Для этого можно написать `?` вместо `!!`:

```
dialog?.
```